# Give users read-only access to Neo4j while doing Batch Update

Tags: neo4j

This is just a general question, not too technical. We have this use-case wherein we are to load hundreds of thousands of records to an existing Neo4j database. Now, we cannot afford to make the database offline because of users who are accessing it. I know that Neo4j requires exclusive lock on the database while it's performing batch updates. Is there a way around my problem? I don't want to lock my database while doing updates. I still want my users to access it - even for just read-only access. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j never requires exclusive lock on the database. It selectively locks portions of the graph that are affected by mutating operations. So there are some things you can do to achieve your goal. Are you a Neo4j Enterprise customer?

**Option 1**: If so, you can run your batch insert on the master node and route users to slaves for reading.

**Option 2**: Alternatively, you could do a "blue-green" style deployment where you:

1. take a backup (B) of your existing database (A), then mark the A database read-only
2. apply your batch inserts onto B either by starting a separate instance, or even better, using `BatchInserter`s. That way, you'll insert your hundreds of thousands in a few seconds
3. start the new database B
4. flip a switch on a load-balancer, so that users start to be routed to the B instead of A
5. take A down

(Please let me know if you need some tips how to make a read-only DB.)

**Option 3**: If you can only afford to run one instance at any one time, then there are techniques you can employ to let your users access the database as usual and still insert large volumes of data. One of them could be using a single-threaded "writer" with a queue that batches write operations. Because one thread only ever writes to the database, you never run into deadlock scenarios and people can happily read from the database. For option 3, I suggest using [GraphAware Writer](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/writer).

I've assumed you are not trying to insert hundreds of thousands of nodes to a running Neo4j database using Cypher. If you are, I would start there and change it to use Java APIs or the `BatchInserter` API.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. That's very helpful. I'm very keen on your Option 3 solution. I may have to start learning GraphAware then.
To answer your question: Eventually, we will be getting an Enterprise edition, but for now we are using the Community edition.

Comment: Alright, let me know if you need any help, Google is your friend for contact details. Good luck!